# HtmlToPlainText no longer included in jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm converting some html to plain text, and I was using jsoup's `HtmlToPlainText`. However, in recent jsoup releases, that code is no longer included because it is supposedly provided only as an example (although the [HtmlToPlainText javadoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/examples/HtmlToPlainText.html) still says it's part of jsoup.jar).

Other than manually copying or packaging that code as an additional library, what else can I use instead? Is there an alternative included in jsoup or at least based on jsoup?

Answer (score 3):

We recently switched from JSoup to Jericho

```
return new Source(html).getRenderer().setMaxLineLength(Integer.MAX_VALUE).setNewLine(null).toString();
```

With this maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.htmlparser.jericho</groupId>
    <artifactId>jericho-html</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not jsoup-based and not very active, but I guess it's an option.

Comment: Agreed. Part of the reason we made the switch is because text conversion is an unintended use of JSoup. Additionally JSoup uses a custom DOM, which is incompatible with FreeMarker's default syntax and we couldnt make the two play nicely together.

Answer (score 2):

The class `HtmlToPlainText` is an example how to use the Jsoup library. If you want to use it you have to copy it's [source code](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/examples/HtmlToPlainText.java) into your own project. All referenced classes are included in the Jsoup library, you just need this one class.

Afterwards you can use it this way:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String text = new HtmlToPlaintext().getPlainText(doc.body());
```

Copying the code into your project has the advantage that you can modify the `HtmlToPlainText` class and adapt it to your needs, e.g if links are shown with their url or not.